# Find the division remainder of a number

Tags: python, modulo, integer-division

How could I go about finding the division remainder of a number in Python?

For example:
If the number is 26 and divided number is 7, then the division remainder is 5.
(since 7+7+7=21 and 26-21=5.)

---

<sub>For simple divisibility testing, see [How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217).</sub>

Comment: I'd suggest looking up the [modulo](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator

Answer (score 276, accepted):

you are looking for the modulo operator:

```
a % b
```

for example:

```
>>> 26 % 7
5
```

Of course, maybe they wanted you to implement it yourself, which wouldn't be too difficult either.

Comment: Note that the modulo operator always returns a positive number, so for negative numbers it might not be what you would expect when talking about the remainder: `-10 % 3 == 2`. However `a/b*b + a%b == a` still holds true, since python always rounds towards -Infinity, unlike some other languages, which round towards 0 but would return -1.

Comment: That's because Python's `%` performs a true modulus, which returns values on the range `[0, divisor)` and pairs well with floored division (towards negative infinity). C languages use the `%` operator for remainder operations which returns values on the range `(-divisor, divisor)` and pairs well with standard division (towards zero).

Answer (score 239):

The remainder of a division can be discovered using the operator `%`:

```
>>> 26%7
5
```

In case you need both the quotient and the modulo, there's the builtin `divmod` function:

```
>>> seconds= 137
>>> minutes, seconds= divmod(seconds, 60)
```

Answer (score 75):

`26 % 7` (you will get remainder)

`26 / 7` (you will get divisor, can be float value)

`26 // 7` (you will get divisor, only integer value)

Comment: Is it possible to get both in a single line? `divisor, remainder = 26 <operation symbol> 7`

Comment: @Guimoute please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848159/6899) in this same question.

Answer (score 41):

If you want to get quotient and remainder in one line of code (more general usecase), use:

```
quotient, remainder = divmod(dividend, divisor)
#or
divmod(26, 7)
```

Comment: An easier way to compute `quotient` is to use the `//`. `quotient =  dividend // divisor`

Answer (score 26):

From Python 3.7, there is a new `math.remainder()` function:

```
from math import remainder
print(remainder(26,7))
```

Output:

```
-2.0  # not 5
```

Note, as above, [it's not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43848660/6260170) as `%`.

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/math.html#math.remainder):

> math.**remainder**(x, y)
>
> Return the IEEE 754-style remainder of x with
> respect to y. For finite x and finite nonzero y, this is the
> difference x - n*y, where n is the closest integer to the exact value
> of the quotient x / y. If x / y is exactly halfway between two
> consecutive integers, the nearest even integer is used for n. The
> remainder r = remainder(x, y) thus always satisfies abs(r) <= 0.5 *
> abs(y).
>
> Special cases follow IEEE 754: in particular, remainder(x, math.inf)
> is x for any finite x, and remainder(x, 0) and remainder(math.inf, x)
> raise ValueError for any non-NaN x. If the result of the remainder
> operation is zero, that zero will have the same sign as x.
>
> On platforms using IEEE 754 binary floating-point, the result of this
> operation is always exactly representable: no rounding error is
> introduced.

[Issue29962](https://bugs.python.org/issue29962) describes the rationale for creating the new function.

Comment: math.remainder may not work the way you expect example for python 3.7

>>> math.remainder(-2.99,2)
-0.9900000000000002
>>> math.remainder(-3,2)
1.0

Answer (score 20):

If you want to avoid modulo, you can also use a combination of the four basic operations :)

```
26 - (26 // 7 * 7) = 5
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the % instead of the / when you divide. This will return the remainder for you. So in your case

```
26 % 7 = 5
```

Answer (score 5):

We can solve this by using modulus operator (%)

26 % 7 = 5;

but 
26 / 7 = 3 because it will give quotient but % operator will give remainder.

Comment: If you use Python 2,  26 / 7 = 3 , for Python 3, 26/7 is about 3.7142857142857144

Answer (score 4):

Modulo would be the correct answer, but if you're doing it manually this should work.

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")
div = input("Enter a divisor: ")

while num >= div:
    num -= div
print num
```

Comment: Works only if num is >= 0 and dif >0.

Answer (score 3):

You can find remainder using modulo operator
Example

```
a=14
b=10
print(a%b)
```

It will print 4

Comment: This answer is misleading, the question was explicitly asking "remainder". Python uses module for `%` operator, what is mathematically different. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/what-is-the-result-of-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If you want the remainder of your division problem, just use the actual remainder rules, just like in mathematics. Granted this won't give you a decimal output.

```
valone = 8
valtwo = 3
x = valone / valtwo
r = valone - (valtwo * x)
print "Answer: %s with a remainder of %s" % (x, r)
```

If you want to make this in a calculator format, just substitute `valone = 8`
with `valone = int(input("Value One"))`. Do the same with `valtwo = 3`, but different vairables obviously.

Comment: you have to cast `valone/valtwo` to int. else it will result in a float number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an integer version of remainder in Python, which should give the same results as C's "%" operator:

```
def remainder(n, d):
    return (-1 if n < 0 else 1) * (abs(n) % abs(d))
```

Expected results:

```
remainder(123, 10)   ==  3
remainder(123, -10)  ==  3
remainder(-123, 10)  == -3
remainder(-123, -10) == -3
```

Answer (score -1):

you can define a function and call it remainder with 2 values like rem(number1,number2) that returns number1%number2
then create a while and set it to true then print out two inputs for your function holding number 1 and 2 then print(rem(number1,number2)

Comment: Please add a working example. Explaining some theoretical code might be hard to understand.