# Python - i can't understand this error

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user for 4 integers and prints the largest odd number that was entered. Here is the code:

```
a = raw_input("Enter an int: ")
b = raw_input("Enter an int: ")
c = raw_input("Enter an int: ")
d = raw_input("Enter an int: ")

numbers = [a, b, c, d]
odd_numbers = []
print numbers
for i in numbers:
    if i%2!=0:
        odd_numbers.append(i)
    else:
        print "This is not an odd number."


for nums in odd_numbers:
    max_num = max(odd_numbers)
    print max_num
```

And here is the error that I'm receiving:

```
line 10, in <module>
  if i%2!=0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try this - a = input("Enter an int: ")

Comment: @TanveerAlam NO. Never recomment python2's `input` to a beginner without a very good reason and without explicitly describing all issues like security holes and performance problems this introduces. Especially not when there is a much better alternative available which does not have any of these issues. The correct way here is of course to simply do `int(raw_input("..."))`.

Comment: You should also explain why this is different from using raw_input @TanveerAlam AND put it as an answer though I should imagine this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Comment: Thanks l4mpi and Paul.

Comment: Thanks! Converting the inputs to int did the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You are input is `string`  convert it into `int`

```
>>> a =raw_input("Enter an int: ")
Enter an int: 10
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
```

Try This :

```
a =int(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
b = int(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
c = int(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
d = int(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
```

OR

```
for i in numbers:
    if int(i)%2!=0:
             odd_numbers.append(i)
```

Your Output Should be look like this :

```
>>> 
Enter an int: 10
Enter an int: 20
Enter an int: 20
Enter an int: 50
[10, 20, 20, 50]
This is not an odd number.
This is not an odd number.
This is not an odd number.
This is not an odd number.
```

Answer (score 3):

[`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string. As a result, `numbers` list becomes a list of strings. `%` operation behavior depends on the variable type, in case of string it is a [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) operation:

```
>>> s = "3"
>>> s % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

In case of `int`, it gives you a [division remainder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584586/find-the-division-remainder-of-a-number):

```
>>> n = 3
>>> n % 2
1
```

You need to convert all the inputs to `int`:

```
a = int(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
b = int(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
c = int(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
d = int(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
```

To avoid having a redundant code, you can simplify filling the `numbers` list using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
numbers = [int(raw_input("Enter an int: ")) for _ in xrange(4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You input strings but you need to do calculations with ints.
I you do `print type(a)` for instance you will see that you actually got a string as input. The way to parse it to an int is to use the built in function `int()`.

```
a = raw_input("Enter an int: ")
b = raw_input("Enter an int: ")
c = raw_input("Enter an int: ")
d = raw_input("Enter an int: ")

numbers = [a, b, c, d]
odd_numbers = []
print numbers
for i in numbers:
    value = int(i)
    if value%2!=0:
        odd_numbers.append(value)
    else:
        print "This is not an odd number."


for nums in odd_numbers:
    max_num = max(odd_numbers)
    print max_num
```

Answer (score 0):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) will return you a string. So, each element in `numbers` are string like

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

When you try `i%2`, python evaluates `%` as the [string formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) but could not find any place-holder in the string for formatting and raise error. So you must parse your input to  `int`

```
a = int(raw_input("Enter an int: "))
```

Or you can use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), which will evaluate your input to proper type (int in your case)

```
a = input("Enter an int: ")
```

But using `input` is not recommended if you are not experienced with it and `eval` as it [states in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.
>
> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.
>
> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.