# Python: find the first even number in a list using a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to write a function that returns the first even number in a list, using a while loop

```
def first_even(list):
    while i%2 !=0:   #I'm not sure if this is a good start for the while loop, but I think I'm supposed to use something%2...
        #no idea what to do here
```

Comment: use the Div function ! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584586/find-the-division-remainder-of-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

A good and very short coding style will be:

```
  for i in list:
     if i%2 == 0:
        return i
```