# Difference between Python 3.7 math.remainder and %(modulo operator)

Tags: python, math, cpython, python-3.7

From [What’s New In Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html)
we can see that there is new [`math.remainder`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#math). It says

> Return the IEEE 754-style remainder of x with respect to y. For finite x and finite nonzero y, this is the difference `x - n*y`, where n is the closest integer to the exact value of the quotient `x / y`. If `x / y` is exactly halfway between two consecutive integers, the nearest even integer is used for `n`. The remainder `r = remainder(x, y)` thus always satisfies `abs(r) <= 0.5 * abs(y)`.
>
> Special cases follow IEEE 754: in particular, `remainder(x, math.inf)` is x for any finite x, and `remainder(x, 0)` and `remainder(math.inf, x)` raise `ValueError` for any non-NaN x. If the result of the remainder operation is zero, that zero will have the same sign as x.
>
> On platforms using IEEE 754 binary floating-point, the result of this operation is always exactly representable: no rounding error is introduced.

But we also remember that there is [`%`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) symbol which is

> remainder of `x / y`

We also see that there is a note to operator:

> Not for complex numbers. Instead convert to floats using `abs()` if appropriate.

I haven't tried to run Python 3.7 if it's even possible.

But i tried

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> 100 % math.inf
100.0
>>> math.inf % 100
nan
>>> 100 % 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

So difference would be, instead of `nan` and `ZeroDivisionError` we would get `ValueError` as it says in docs.

So the question is what is the difference between `%` and `math.remainder`? Would `math.remainder` also work with complex numbers(`%` lacks from it)? What is the main advantage?

Here is the [**source** of `math.remainder`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L608-L696) from official CPython github repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Return the IEEE 754-style remainder of x with respect to y. For finite
>   x and finite nonzero y, this is the difference `x - n*y`, where n is the
>   closest integer to the exact value of the quotient `x / y`. If `x / y` is
>   exactly halfway between two consecutive integers, the nearest even
>   integer is used for n. The remainder `r = remainder(x, y)` thus always
>   satisfies `abs(r) <= 0.5 * abs(y)`.

for the modulo this is `m = x - n*y` where `n` is the `floor(x/y)`, so `0 <= m < y` instead of `abs(r) <= 0.5 * abs(y)` for the remainder.

so

```
modulo(2.7, 1) = 0.7
remainder(2.7, 1) = -0.3
```

Comment: Actually it's `-0.3` for `remainder(2.7, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MaartenFabré, I wasn't being attentive to details:

> #### `math.remainder()` is the difference `x - n*y`, where `n` is the closest integer to the exact value of the quotient `x / y`

I built Python 3.7:

```
Python 3.7.0a0 (heads/master:f34c685020, May  8 2017, 15:35:30)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
```

And here are differences:

Zero as divisor:

```
>>> math.remainder(1, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
>>> 1 % 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Basic numbers, where `math.remainder(x, y) < x % y`

```
>>> math.remainder(5, 3)
-1.0
>>> 5 % 3
2
```

Complex numbers:

```
>>> math.remainder(3j + 2, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
>>> (3j + 2) % 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't mod complex numbers.
```

Infinity(`math.inf`)

```
>>> math.remainder(3, math.inf)
3.0
>>> 3 % math.inf
3.0
>>> math.remainder(math.inf, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
>>> math.inf % 3
nan
```