# Different result of math.remainder() and % operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why are the amounts of this two different?

math.remainder(3,2)

and

3%2

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs? https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.remainder

Comment: math.remainder(3, 2) returns -1.0 for some reason

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Python 3.7 math.remainder and %(modulo operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845375/difference-between-python-3-7-math-remainder-and-modulo-operator)