# What does the % mean in arithmatic expressions in Python?

Tags: python

I am taking a codeacademy beginners course in Python.  What does the character "%" mean in this expression - 45 % 12?  I am using Python 2.7.5.  i have looked at various references, and cannot find it.

Comment: It's a modulus operator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python

Comment: @mhlester Yes, that's a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Yeah I'm out of flags for the day :)

Comment: I have some slight doubt that you have looked at "various references"....

Comment: second hit with google, so -1: "% operator python" resulted in "Modulus - Divides left hand operand by right hand operand and returns remainder". I hardly believe you could not find a proper explanation, this operator exists in so many languages. Sorry for your first question.

Answer (score 0):

It's the modulus operator - 45 divided by 12 = 3 and 9/12. In short, it would return 9.

It's a neat way of looping up to a certain count

eg the following will run on alternate rows...

```
for i in range[0,100]
    if i % 2 == 0:
        #Even row
    else:
        #Odd row
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` (read "mod" or "modulo") means divide by and return the remainder:

```
x = 8%3
```

The above expression says "divide 8 by 3 and compute the remainder. Assign this remainder to `x`"