# Getting a strange NameError trying to implement a Caesar Cypher

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what ive done so far but this keeps popping up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tom/Documents/python 2.py", line 20, in <module>
    print (cypherText)
NameError: name 'cypherText' is not defined
```

My code:

```
message = input("what is your message? ").lower()
Shift = int(input("What is your shift? "))

def caesar(message, shift):
    cypherText= " "
    for ch in message:
        if ch.isAlpha():
            stayInAlpha = ord(ch) + shift
        if stayInAlphabet > ord ('z'):
            stayInAlphabet -= 27
        if stayInAlphabet < ord ('a'):
            stayInAlphabet += 27
        finalletter = chr(stayInAlphabet)
        cypherText += finalletter



print ("Your message is:")
print (cypherText)
```

It is at this last bit where I think it all goes wrong but i have no idea why

Comment: A quick comment: Any time you are doing anything with crypto, whether it's a simple Caesar cipher, RSA, or Rijndael, you will need to know how to use the modulo operator `%`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `cypherText` is defined only inside your function.

Just modify your function to `return` it.

Also, since `caesar` is defined as function, it needs to be invoked, or else the code inside it will not run. *Note that I have not tested your `caesar` function.* **If it is broken, it will still be broken.**

```
def caesar(message, shift):
    cypherText= " "
    for ch in message:
        if ch.isAlpha():
            stayInAlpha = ord(ch) + shift
        if stayInAlphabet > ord ('z'):
            stayInAlphabet -= 27
        if stayInAlphabet < ord ('a'):
            stayInAlphabet += 27
        finalletter = chr(stayInAlphabet)
        cypherText += finalletter
    return cypherText

print("Your message is")
print (caesar(message, Shift))
```