# How Python calculates % function can some one please explain 3%5

Tags: python-2.7, percentage

How Python calculates `%` function? can some one please explain `3%5` outcome as `3` in Python? Answer for `5%3` is also showing `3`. I use python 2.7

Comment: `5%3` should be equal to 2. `%` is modulo operator as in C, C++ and Java. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The Python `%` operator isn't percentage, it's modulo.  That means the remainder part of a division. Remember when you were a kid and your math problems would be like 11 divided by 3 = 3 R 2 (remainder 2)?  That's what % does.  `5 % 3` = 2.

If you want to calculate percentage, do that yourself like `A * 100.0 / B`.