# Last 2 digits of an integer? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

With my code, I want to get the last two digits of an integer. But when I make x a positive number, it will take the first x digits, if it is a negative number, it will remove the first x digits.

Code:

```
number_of_numbers = 1
num = 9
while number_of_numbers <= 100:
  done = False
  num = num*10
  num = num+1
  while done == False:
    num_last = int(repr(num)[x])
    if num_last%14 == 0:
      number_of_numbers = number_of_numbers + 1
      done = True
    else:
      num = num + 1
print(num)
```

Answer (score 49):

Why don't you extract the absolute value of the number modulus 100? That is, use

```
 abs(num) % 100
```

to extract the last two digits?

In terms of performance and clarity, this method is hard to beat.

Comment: You'll get 8 for 208 and 0 for 200. Make sure that is what you want. A safer solution is str(num)[-2:]

Answer (score 16):

To get the last 2 digits of `num` I would use a 1 line simple hack:

```
str(num)[-2:]
```

This would give a string.
To get an int, just wrap with int:

```
int(str(num)[-2:])
```

Answer (score 6):

Simpler way to extract last two digits of the number *(less efficient)* is to convert the number to `str` and slice the last two digits of the number. For example:

```
# sample function
def get_last_digits(num, last_digits_count=2):
    return int(str(num)[-last_digits_count:])
    #       ^ convert the number back to `int`
```

OR, you may achieve it via using modulo `%` operator *(more efficient)*, (to know more, check [How does % work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python)) as:

```
def get_last_digits(num, last_digits_count=2):
    return abs(num) % (10**last_digits_count)
    #       ^ perform `%` on absolute value to cover `-`ive numbers
```

Sample run:

```
>>> get_last_digits(95432)
32
>>> get_last_digits(2)
2
>>> get_last_digits(34644, last_digits_count=4)
4644
```

Comment: Conversion operations are expensive. Why would you want to do this if there are simpler ways?

Comment: @Shiva: Now I have explicitly mentioned that conversion is less efficient. Converison is *simpler* to implement (*atleast as per me*)

Answer (score 3):

to get the last 2 digits of an integer.

```
a = int(input())
print(a % 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

float(str(num)[-2:])