# How to remove characters from each element in a list

Tags: python, list

I would like to remove the first two characters from each element (which are currently ints) that i have in a list. This is what i have:

```
lst = [2011,2012,3013]
```

I would like to get this

```
lst= [11,12,13]
```

I do not want a solution with some sort of replace 20 or 30 with '' however.

Comment: Don't name lists `list`

Comment: You can use `x = [abs(i)%100 for i in x]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last 2 digits of an integer? Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664806/last-2-digits-of-an-integer-python-3)

Comment: Is my answer ok or are you trying to remove exactly 2 leading digits from every value? In that case what about numbers with 2 or less digits?

Answer (score 3):

Given `source= [2011,-2012,-3013]` :

#### Result as ints, unsigned:

```
dest = [abs(x)%100 for x in source]
```

#### Result as ints, signed

```
dest = [(abs(x)%100)*(1 if x > 0 else -1) for x in source]
```

#### Result as strings, unsigned (preserves leading zeroes):

```
dest = list(map(lambda x : str(x)[-2:],source)
```

#### Result as strings, signed (preserves leading zeroes):

```
dest = list(map(lambda x : ("-" if str(x)[0]=="-" else "")+str(x)[-2:],source))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
list = [abs(number)%100 for number in list]
```

And it's a bad practice to name lists list. Use another name.

Comment: Please do not name lists `list` it overrides a builtin.

Comment: Best suggestion ever :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use module by 100,like:

```
my_list= [2011,2012,3013]
expected_list = [i%100 for i in my_list]
```

If you have negative numbers in `my_list`:

```
expected_list=[abs(i)%100 for i in my_list]
```

Or use string slicing:

```
expected_list = [int(str(i)[2:]) for i in my_list] #[2:],because you want to remove first two numbers
```

Please try avoid using reserved keywords as you variable name, as you have used `list` as your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo:

just modulo each element with like 100

```
list= [2011,2012,3013]
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] %= 100
```

Comment: Please do not name lists `list`, it overrides a builtin