# Going back to begining of a string

Tags: python, string, encryption

I am coding a Caesar cipher. The key is an integer from 1 to 25. This cipher rotates the letters of the alphabet (A to Z). The encoding replaces each letter
with the 1st to 25th next letter in the alphabet (wrapping Z to A). So key 2 encrypts “HI” to “JK”, but key 20 encrypts “HI” to “BC”.

But If I put in 
"I am super" it will output "k kc oouwrgt" when it should be "k co uwrgt" with a key of 2. It will also not go back to the beginning of the alphabet e.g 'x' will not go to 'a' with a key of 2. I use python 3.4.1

```
encode = []
a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz"
a = list(a)
print(a)

e = input("encode or decode --->")
text = input("Sentence -->").lower()
text = list(text)
print(text)


Key = int(input("Key -->"))
if Key > 25:
    print("Too high")
else:
   print(Key)

if e == "encode":
    for i, item in enumerate(text):
        if item == " ":
            encode.append(letter)
        else:
            num = a.index(item)
            num = num + int(Key)
            letter = a[num]
            encode.append(letter)

for i in range(len(encode)):
    print(encode[i])
```

Answer (score 4):

When you encounter a space, you append the last letter again, instead of `item`:

```
if item == " ":
    encode.append(letter)
```

This causes `k` and `o` to appear twice when the key is `2`; you re-appended the encoded `i` -> `k` and `m` -> `o` results.

You need to use the [`%` modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to make your index 'wrap round':

```
num = (num + Key) % 26
```

I removed the `int()` call, you already turned `Key` to an integer earlier.

Other tips:

- You don't need to turn `a` into a list; strings are sequences too and support indexing and the `.index()`method directly. The same applies to `text`; just loop over the string itself.
- You are not using `i` in the `for i, item in enumerate(text):` loop; drop `enumerate` altogether: `for item in text:`.
- You *could* just print your encoded characters directly in that loop, no need to use an `encode` list and a separate loop.
- The [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) would let you print your encoded text all on one line:  `print(''.join(encode))` instead of your last `for` loop.
- The absolute fastest method of encoding a string is to use a *translation table*, a dictionary mapping input characters to output characters, and the [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). You can use the [`str.maketrans()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to make that table:

  ```
  import string

  a = string.ascii_lowercase  # why type yourself when the stdlib has these?
  text = input("Sentence -->").lower()
  Key = int(input("Key -->"))
  mapping = str.maketrans(a, a[Key:] + a[:Key])  # letters to rotated letters
  print(text.translate(mapping))
  ```

  The trick lies in creating the second string for `str.maketrans()`; using slicing it is easy to create a rotated string, by taking everything from position `Key` onwards, and the first `Key` characters at the end:

  ```
  >>> a[Key:] + a[:Key]
  'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxzab'
  ```

Comment: `a[Key:] + a[:Key]` is a cool trick, it also works with negative indices for decoding.

Comment: @EricDuminil: or just use `str.translate(a[Key:] + a[:Key], a)`.

Comment: This is great, thank you for taking the time to explain it :)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious solution would be to use [modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python) for the alphabet index:

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the
>   first argument by the second.

```
>>> 12 % 26
12
>>> 26 % 26
0
>>> 28 % 26
2
```

As a bonus, you wouldn't need to check the key is lower than 25, and you'll never get an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

```
encode = []
a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz"

e = input("encode or decode --->")
text = input("Sentence -->").lower()

key = int(input("Key -->"))

if e == "encode":
    for i, item in enumerate(text):
        if item == " ":
            encode.append(item)
        else:
            num = a.index(item)
            num = num + int(key)
            letter = a[num % 26]
            encode.append(letter)

for letter in encode:
    print(letter)
```

A few notes:

- a string is already an iterable of characters. No need to convert it to a list
- `letter` wasn't defined in `if item == " "`
- to iterate over a list, you don't need the length or the index.
- to decode the message, just change the sign of the key. It should work just like encode, thanks to modulo : `-2 % 26 # => 24`

As an example:

```
encode or decode --->encode
Sentence -->i am super
Key -->2
k

c
o

u
w
r
g
t
```

and

```
encode or decode --->encode
Sentence -->k co uwrgt
Key -->-2
i

a
m

s
u
p
e
r
```