# I cannot understand the remainder operator for negative values in python

Tags: python

for instance,-10 % 3 = 2, this does not make any sense as the definition for % is remainder. Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answer @COLDSPEED referenced, it's worth noting that % is the _modulo_ operator if you're looking for more information. You can also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python) for general information about how it works in python.

Answer (score 0):

-10 = 3(-4)+2, hence the remainder is 2 mathematically.

Alternatively notice that that 10 % 3 is equal to 1. Hence the remainder of -10 % 3 should be -1 which is equal to 3-1 = 2 modulo 3.

By the rule that a % b follows the sign of b and |a%b| < b, 2 is returned as the answer.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. Please see the marked duplicates above, which explain _why_ the modulo operator works that way.

Comment: Thanks, as you suggested, there is two hidden rules applied for ' % ', am I understanding correct?

Comment: yup, as pointed out by the accepted answer shared by coldspeed. I miss out the rule out a%b follows the sign of b back then.