# How to restart the iteration of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a problem with a program in Python and I can't find an answer to my question. Let's suppose I have a list containing all the chars of the alphabet, that means from A to Z.

```
list = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
```

I want to take a random char form that list. Let's suppose Z. Now I want to iterate over that list 13 times. Let me explain better: if I am on the Z, `Z + 13` must be **M** because I would do A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M. If I would be on the A and I'd want to use 25 for example it would be easy because it would be Z the final result. But if I put a 27 (so it goes over the max numbers of items in the list) how can I restart the list after the 25 so `A + 27` would be **B**?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the modulus operator, `%`?

Comment: I think you are looking for modulo function, https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: You are looking for the [modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python) operator.

Comment: I don't get it, how could the % operator achieve that?

Comment: `codecs.encode()` with `"rot13"`

Comment: You could do something like this: `element = l[(r + n) % len(l)]`, where `r` is the random index number of the list: `[0-25]`, `n` is the number you choose e.g. `13` and then you use the modulus operator `%` with the list's length, so that the value you will get will range from `0` to `len(list)-1`, that is, within bounds.

Comment: pls stop using `list` as a variable name.

Comment: "Iteration" has nothing to do with this. You aren't "iterating" over the list "13 times"; for any given input letter you want *one* output letter. The point is to find the *corresponding* one. The `%` operator helps you do this by using math to determine the index of the corresponding letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, you could use `% len(lst)`:

```
lst = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
print(lst[0])  # A
print(lst[(0+27) % len(lst)])  # B
```

**Explanation**:

`lst[0]` gives `A`. 
`lst[0+27]` does not exist (length of `lst` is `26`). There you should be using `%` operator which follows a circular path through `lst`.

```
27 % 26 = 1
```

So, in effect you call `lst[1]` when you do `lst[(0+27) % len(lst)]`.

**Note**:
Do not use `list` as your variable name. It shadows the in-built `list`. Try `lst` or something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Your answer matches all my questions and problems.

Comment: Glad I could help you. @OverLoop

Answer (score 1):

I think you can access the list element by `list[index % len(list)]`

Comment: @OverLoop Why not? What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Little example with a predifined index with value 34:

```
l = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
index=34
print(l[index%len(l)]) # result 'I'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
l = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
n = 13 # Chosen number (you can assign any integer you want)
r = 25 # Index of Z
element = l[(r + n) % len(l)]
print("Element: ", element)
```

Output:

```
Element:  M
```

You can use the `randint` function from the `random` module to assign a random number for `r`, as well as `n`.