# Python Comparing Large Numbers

Tags: python, numbers, largenumber

How does one compare large numbers python?
I have the following two numbers:

x = 99 ^ 85, y = 73 ^ 62.

Computing both numbers in the python interpreter gives the following results:

```
>>> x = 99 ** 85
>>> x
42559012338865490805205255842468783301592970011660094241731171697575386634867177511754750618655432231509140219114042806178869109409115320236642740915044006252790234308499
>>> y = 73 ** 62
>>> y
33575100975948386797110696048991269305533302609246066947133332393856972076850553634350302934134549900847114729991729
```

Even without computing the results it's quite obvious that x will be greater than y. I performed `mod 1000000007` on both numbers in order to reduce the number of digits. I got the following results:

```
>>> mod = 1000000007
>>> x % mod
195405172
>>> y % mod
297675700
>>>
```

As you can see the mod results of the numbers results in **y** being greater than **x**. Is there an efficient of comparing large numbers and get the right results. I don't think this problem is bound to python alone though the context of the question is under python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why *shouldn't* y % mod > x % mod?  Note that 19 % 10 > 98 % 10.

Comment: @ScottHunter so the mod of  a small number is sometimes greater than the mod of a large number? If this is the case, is there no efficient way of comparing large numbers?

Comment: Can't you just use floating point numbers?

Comment: @TimLudwinski it doesn't make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this question [How does % work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python)

Modulo give you the remainder of a number.  So 4 % 10 = 4 and 14 % 10 = 4.  So for directly comparing two numbers you will lose information by using modulo.
Comparing large numbers is pretty quick in python.   Use ipython's %timeit to see.

```
%timeit (99 ** 85)>( 73 ** 62 )
```

On my system ( an older i7, 14 GB of ram) it took 46.3 nano seconds which is about as fast as any operation in python.

Comment: Please see the comment I've made on Dadep's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 'size' of the number have a very small influence in term of execution :
'big numbers' :

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a=99**85; b=73**52; a>b')
0.07298588752746582
```

'small numbers':

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a=5**2; b=6**3; a>b')
0.07102680206298828
```

If the question is how to compare numbers in python use `>` and `<` :

```
>>> 5>9
False
>>> 5<9
True
```

Comment: I've limited the scope of the powers to just one power. if you were to try something like `56 ^ 67 ^ 78 ^ 90......` You'll realize things begin to slow down really quickly.

Comment: @Michael, Did you check if the time delai is due to generating number `85**69**45` or to the comparison of to large number `a<b` ?

Comment: Yes I did. It's quite fast. But increase the number of exponents to about 100 it becomes slow. It even becomes slower when you are making multiple comparisons in a list.