# How can I set a range to work with numpy's arange

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to create a weather widget in a Flask application. I am stuck on working with wind direction in degrees (angle).

If we use the following image as a representation:

### Wind Directions

[image]

When working with wind direction we are limited to a 360 degree range. I would like to assign an icon based on which range within 360 degrees I get for wind direction, to help you understand here is some information:

```
| Cardinal Direction | Degree Direction |
|:------------------:|------------------|
|          N         |   348.75 - 11.25 |
|         NNE        |    11.25 - 33.75 |
|         NE         |    33.75 - 56.25 |
|         ENE        |    56.25 - 78.75 |
|          E         |   78.75 - 101.25 |
|         ESE        |  101.25 - 123.75 |
|         SE         |  123.75 - 146.25 |
|         SSE        |  146.25 - 168.75 |
|          S         |  168.75 - 191.25 |
|         SSW        |  191.25 - 213.75 |
|         SW         |  213.75 - 236.25 |
|         WSW        |  236.25 - 258.75 |
|          W         |  258.75 - 281.25 |
|         WNW        |  281.25 - 303.75 |
|         NW         |  303.75 - 326.25 |
|         NNW        |  326.25 - 348.75 |
```

I will store the keys/values in a dict and create an if elif else loop that will do something like the following:

```python
from numpy import arange
degrees = the_json_response['wind']['deg']
wind_directions = {
    'N': arange(348.75, 11.25, 0.25),
    ...
}
degrees_range = range(0, 360)
if degrees in wind_direction['N']:
    dirction = north_icon
elif degrees in wind_direction['NNE']:
    direction = north_north_east_icon
```

The above is only pseudo code.. To summarize, How can I apply this so that we only ever work with a 360 degree range because obviously it will throw errors when working with North wind direction due to it being in a range of 348.75 - 11.25, we need to tell it we are working with 360 degrees.

The reason I cannot for the life of my figure this out is I never learnt complex mathmatics (which to me this is). If anyone has a suggestion on how I can apply this in a *better* way I am very open to those suggestions.

Comment: Modulo operator?

Comment: Why are you using `arange`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am using arange so i can use a range of floats in steps of 0.25..

Comment: @MadPhysicist do you care to elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @JamieLindsey To make sure I understand you correctly: given a degree in range [0,360] you want to assign a cardinal direction to it according to the table, right?

Comment: @Jamie. I've written up an answer that should explain what I mean.

Comment: @today yes that is correct, but as you can see in the table its not as simple as using a range(0, 360) because there is a point where we have put a range of (348.75, 11.25) which doesnt work with a standard range function (unless im wrong)

Comment: @JamieLindsey As MadPhysicist has mentioned in his/her comment and answer, you can simply store the directions in list and then use modulo/division operator to find the correct direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap any number to a particular range, use modulo (`%`): [How does % work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4432208/2988730). Luckily for you, the python implementation makes the sign of the result always equal to the right hand operand. Here are some examples of how modulo wraps everything to the desired range:

```
>>> 45 % 360
45
>>> -38 % 360
322
>>> 1000 % 360
280
```

Given this, it is very easy to map any value in degrees to a letter abbreviation. Each abbreviation represents a window 22.5 degrees wide. The windows are offset from zero by 11.25 degrees, so we can get a window index by doing

```
from math import floor

index = floor(((deg + 11.25) % 360) / 22.5)
```

This index will always be a number between zero and 15. You can use it directly to index into a list of points of the compass, without any dictionaries or expensive searches:

```
list_of_points = ['N', 'NNE', 'NE', ..., 'NW', 'NNW']

def deg_to_point(deg):
    return list_of_points[floor(((deg + 11.25) % 360) / 22.5)]
```

This works because all your bins are the same size. If you wanted more points on your compass rose, you could halve 11.25 and 22.5, for example. If you had unequal bins, your best bet would be to normalize your input using modulo, and then do a binary search on the bin edges.

Comment: you sir are a genius! I am pondering over the `deg_to_point()` function to learn how to do more like this.. Thank you so much! I think I actually understand this which is normally not the case with mathematics. Answer marked as accepted.

Comment: @Jamie. You do what you can. Glad it helped you understand

Comment: Also I was reading that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4432208/2988730) a when I got a notification of your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea: You can check if the upper limit of the degree range is lower than the lower limit then create `arange` in two step procedure. For example: `348.75, 11.25` is the only case where the upper limit `11.25` is less than the lower limit `348.75` which means due to periodicity, `360` comes in between. For all other degree ranges and directions, the upper limit is more than the lower limit. Hence you can create `N` in such a way that you include `360` in one range and the remaining values in the other.

```
x = np.arange( 348.75, 360, 0.25) 
y = np.arange(0.25, 11.25, 0.25) 
'N' = np.concatenate((x ,y), axis=0)
```

Just an idea, may be you can improve upon it.

Comment: I honestly have to say I don't understand the logic.. This gives values exponent equal to 0, 1 and 2 and the decimal point is in the wrong place - e.g.  `array([3.4875e+02, 3.4900e+02, 3.4925e+02, 3.4950e+02` ... maybe I should edit my question to let everyone know I am not the best mathematician

Comment: For values above 100, exponent will be 2, for two digit numbers, 1 and for single digit, 0. Its just the representation. 3e+02 and 300 mean the same thing

Comment: your equations are not within my capabilities yet, as in I don't have a clue what you mean lol. MadPhysicist has provided a perfect working example which i understand. Thank you for your effort though I appreciate it.