# failing to compare two numbers converted from string

Tags: python-3.x

here is my code... It's considering only 8 and 88 among 1 to 100 which aren't karpekar numbers...failing at if condition(s==n)

```
 def kaprekarNumbers(p, q):
  for i in range(p,q+1):
    n=i
    m=str(i*i);
    sl1=m[:int(len(m)/2)]
    sl2=m[int(len(m)/2):]
    if(sl2==""):
        sl2=0
    s=int(sl2)+int(sl2)
    print(s==n)
    if s==n:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using strings to process numbers is not usually a good idea.

You can get the number of digits of a number `n` with

```
math.ceil(math.log10(n))
```

You can get the last `a` digits of a number `n` with

```
n % a
```

(See: [How does % work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4432208/1115360))

You can get the first `a` digits of a number `n` with

```
p // (10 ** a)
```

Those would be useful for base-10 [Kaprekar numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaprekar_number).

[Please note, I do not have a copy of Python to hand to check those.]