# python array notation shorthand :"k%parents.shape[0]" mean?

Tags: python, arrays, list, notation

I came across this notation today as going through 
this tutorial here:https://towardsdatascience.com/genetic-algorithm-implementation-in-python-5ab67bb124a6

```
parent1_idx = k%parents.shape[0]
```

what is the right-hand side going to return?
and what is the name for this kind of expression?
thanks in advance !

Comment: What are you confused about? It is modulo operator. So, it is `k % <something>`

Comment: presumably `shape` is some sort of indexed attribute of `parents` (i.e. `parents.shape` gets you a list (or something) which you can pull a `[0]` index from). I'm not sure about the k%, though I have seen `%`, IIRC, in string formatting (https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting). If k is a variable, the % is probably a modulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that line in this snippet of code from the mentioned article:

```
for k in range(offspring_size[0]):
     # Index of the first parent to mate.
     parent1_idx = k%parents.shape[0]
     # Index of the second parent to mate.
     parent2_idx = (k+1)%parents.shape[0]
```

Where `parents` is defined as follows:

```
parents = numpy.empty((num_parents, pop.shape[1]))
for parent_num in range(num_parents):
    max_fitness_idx = numpy.where(fitness == numpy.max(fitness))
    max_fitness_idx = max_fitness_idx[0][0]
    parents[parent_num, :] = pop[max_fitness_idx, :]
    fitness[max_fitness_idx] = -99999999999
return parents
```

From the above two lines, it's quite evident that both `k` and `parents.shape[0]` are integers, and hence the line is a simple [modulo  operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4432235/5070837) between two numerical variables: `a = b % c` .

Answer (score 1):

`%` is a operator in python, i-e `Modulus operator - it gives remainder of the division of left operand by the right`