# Print a list for the month with person's name and the date using a function

Tags: python

Hi I'm learning to code in python and thought it would be cool to automate a task I usually do for my room mates. I write out a list of names and the date for each month so that everyone knows whos turn it is for dishes. 
Here's my code:

```
def dish_day_cycle(month, days):
    print('Dish Cycle For %s:' % month)
    dish_list = ['Jen', 'Zack', 'Hector', 'Arron']
    days = days + 1

    for day in range(1, days):
        for i in dish_list:
            print('%s %s : %s' % (month, day, i))
```

The problem is that it repeats everyone's name for each and every day, obviously not what I want. I need it to print only one name per day. Not this:

```
>>> dish_day_cycle(month, days)
Dish Cycle For December:

December 1 : Jen
December 1 : Zack
December 1 : Hector
December 1 : Arron
December 2 : Jen
December 2 : Zack
December 2 : Hector
December 2 : Arron
December 3 : Jen
December 3 : Zack
December 3 : Hector
December 3 : Arron
December 4 : Jen
December 4 : Zack
December 4 : Hector
December 4 : Arron
December 5 : Jen
December 5 : Zack
December 5 : Hector
December 5 : Arron
```

Please let me know how I could correct this function to work properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used a nested for loop, therefore for every day - each of the names is printed along with that day. Use only the outer loop, and calculate who's turn it is. should be something like:

```
for day in range(1, days):
    print('%s %s : %s' % (month, day, dish_list[day % len(dish_list)]))
```

assuming your roomates & you split the dishing equally.

Comment: Nice, but if it were to start at the beginning of the list, the index should start at `0`. I.e. `dish_list[(day - 1) % len(dish_list)]`

Comment: It doesn't matter...I mean, maybe it matters, but I aim to solve the technical problem, not to determine whether Jen or Zack wash the dishes in the first day of December.

Comment: Merely for completeness given the example starts with Jen.

Comment: For added fairness: a month-based list will skip a few persons at the turn of a month. You could use a nth-day-of-the-year based list, but then people might complain at the turn of the year `:)` Perhaps using `%` on a Unix time, which has a fixed starting point, is the most fair in the short run. (It might get complicated around January 19, 2038.)

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem and works perfectly. I did need to change the part that Adam suggested in order to start the list with Jen. I would appreciate if you could explain how this code works to calculate who's turn it is, as I am learning python and would like to understand it.

Comment: The `%` is the modulus operator, and returns the remainder. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through both lists together and repeating the shorter with `itertools.cycle`:

```
import itertools
for day, person in zip(range(1, days), itertools.cycle(dish_list)):
     print('{} {} : {}'.format(month, day, person))
```

Update:

`zip` will pair elements in the two iterables--`range` object of days and `dish_list`--to create a new list of tuple pairs from the two iterables. However, `zip` only creates a list up to the shortest iterable. `itertools.cycle` circumvents this problem so `zip` cycles back to through `dish_list`. The for loop will now cycle through these two together, rather than in a nested fashion in your original code.

Documentation will probably explain better than I just did: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

Comment: This solution also works perfectly by busybear. Thank you and could you please explain what the pieces are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're iterating over the days and then for over the list of names. Imagine running line by line because a for loop only repeats after it has gotten to the end of an item. So you've said in your function, for each day each person has to do the dishes which is why you have all this repetition.

Much easier would be to only have one for loop, and add 1 to day and to dish_list inside that loop as such

```
person = 0 # this will serve as the index of the list

for day in range(days):
    print("%s %s : %s" % (month, day + 1, dish_list[person]))

    if person == 3:
        person = 0
    else:
        person += 1
```

Also just to point out, there should be an indent after defining your function otherwise it will throw off an error. Hope this helps

Comment: This will give an error once the person variable reaches 4. dish_list[4] is out of index.

Comment: Yup thanks for the comments guys! The code above should be error-free

Comment: The code by Tom_G_99 also works perfectly. Error free so just another way of solving this. Thanks