# Add lists of different length cycling over smallest

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```py
a = [50, 17, 54, 26]
b = [19,  7,  8, 18, 36, 8, 18, 36, 18, 14]
```

I want to add to the elements of `b` the corresponding elements of `a`. When the elements of `a` runs out, I want to cycle through `a` to supply the elements. The result should be:

```py
c = [69, 24, 62, 44, 86, 25, 72, 62, 68, 31]
```

What is the "Pythonic" way to implement this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to add the elements from both lists zipped together, and use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) so that the iterator `a` repeats itself as many times as necessary until `b` is exhausted:

```
from itertools import cycle
a = [50, 17, 54, 26]
b = [19,  7,  8, 18, 36, 8, 18, 36, 18, 14]

[i+j for i,j in zip(cycle(a), b)]
```

**Output**

```
[69, 24, 62, 44, 86, 25, 72, 62, 68, 31]
```

---

**Details**

If you take a look at the iterator of tuples generated from the zipped expression:

```
list(zip(cycle(a),b))

[(50, 19),
 (17, 7),
 (54, 8),
 (26, 18),
 (50, 36),
 (17, 8),
 (54, 18),
 (26, 36),
 (50, 18),
 (17, 14)]
```

You can see that the elements in `a` cycle around until the other iterator is exhausted, making it very easy to perform some operation on the interleaved elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want any imports you can use the [modulo operator (%)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/how-does-work-in-python).

```py
a = [50, 17, 54, 26]
b = [19, 7, 8, 18, 36, 8, 18, 36, 18, 14]
[a[i%len(a)]+b[i] for i in range(len(b))]
```

### Output

```
[69, 24, 62, 44, 86, 25, 72, 62, 68, 31]
```