# How to Get Next multiplication Number using in math function

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have one case like a=14 when the user enters 6 then it will be check as next largest number of the multiplication number.

```
if 6*2>14 so not working and then that 6*3>14 so it is working.
```

I have no idea what was the name of the math function.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @dome I need to next multiplication number using of math function

Comment: do you mean *integer division*? `14 // 6 = 2`... meaning `6*2 <= 14` and `6*3 > 14`...

Comment: @HarshitTrivedi are you saying  if `b` is user entered value find smallest `n` such that `b*n > a`

Comment: Next multiplication number of what? Please edit the question to make it clear what you are trying to say @HarshitTrivedi

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I mens that next multiplication number of that number just like 6*3 18>14 like that

Comment: So if input is 6 and 2, the output is 18 ?

Comment: Is the [modulo function %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/what-is-the-result-of-in-python) the name of the math function you're looking for?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh output is 18 and it is any math function for that?

Comment: Sure, I think you can use `math.ceil` for it, check my answer below @HarshitTrivedi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [math.ceil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) to calculate the ceiling of `number/multiplier` and multiply with it `multiplier` to get your result

```
import math

def func(number, multiplier):
    return multiplier * math.ceil(number/multiplier)
```

The output will be

```
print(func(14,6))
#18
print(func(18,6))
#18
print(func(19,6))
#24
```

Example for `number=14` and `multiplier=6`, `math.ceil(14/6)` gives `3`, and `6*3` gives `18`

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want:

```
factor = ((a-1) // n + 1)
```

Where `a` is you number like 14 and n is the smaller number to be multiplied by the `factor`:

```
a = 15
n = 7
factor = ((a-1) // n + 1)
print("factor", factor)
# 3
print("multiplied:", n * ((a-1) // n + 1))
# 21
```

it's not clear from your question what happens with an exact match, but this will return the exact factor:

```
a = 14
n = 7
factor = ((a-1) // n + 1)
print("factor", factor)
# 2
print("multiplied:", n * ((a-1) // n + 1))
#4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my guess on what is meant based on the other comments:

```
user_number= int(input("What is your number? "))

check_number=int(input("What is the number to check against. "))

factor = 1
print(check_number, factor*user_number)
while(check_number>(factor*user_number)):
    print(factor)
    print("Not working.")
    factor+=1

working_factor = check_number%user_number+1
print("using modulo: ", working_factor)
print("Working factor: ",factor)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hello, Can you please give working factor related answer.

Comment: It is at the bottom, it says working factor: 3, the variable factor stores the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
a = 14
b = 6
mutiple = math.floor(a/b)+1
value = mutiple*b

print (mutiple, value)
```