# Converting seconds to hours, minutes, and seconds

Tags: python-3.x, operators

I understand how I would type this in IDLE, but I don't really understand the math behind it. Specifically lines 8 and 11... Can someone walk me through this, so I can understand the basic math that's going on here?

```
# Get a number of seconds from the user.
total_seconds = float(input('Enter a number of seconds: '))

# Get the number of hours.
hours = total_seconds // 3600

# Get the number of remaining minutes.
minutes = (total_seconds // 60) % 60

# Get the number of remaining seconds.
seconds = total_seconds % 60

# Display the results.
print('Here is the time in hours, minutes, and seconds:')
print('Hours:', hours)
print('Minutes:', minutes)
print('Seconds:', seconds)
```

Comment: Say, if I was to enter 11730 seconds, I know i would get back 3.0 hours, 15.0 minutes, and 30.0 seconds. What math is going on that would result in that answer, though?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about the modulo operator. See also [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) and / or [this question / post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432208/what-is-the-result-of-in-python) for more details.

In short, the modulo operator divides and returns the remainder of the division or 0 in case there is no remainder.

Lets look at your example step by step:

```
>>> total_seconds = 11730
>>> total_seconds / 3600
3.2583333333333333
```

So you have 3 hours and the decimal part specifies minutes and seconds.

```
>>> total_seconds / 60 
195.5
```

You already know that you have 3 full hours thus you can remove it

```
>>> (total_seconds / 60) - 3 * 60
15.5
```

which is the same as

```
>>> (total_seconds / 60) % 60
15.5
```

So you got 3 hours, 15 minutes and half a minute which are actually 30 seconds. This is exactly what is returned by

```
>>> total_seconds % 60
30
```

Note also `//` is the floor division (returns the chopped of integer part of the standard division `/`).